# BizHawk 2.1.1: read("*number") always returns 0 in Lua

Tags: lua, emulation

I'm trying to run the brilliant Mar I/O artificial intelligence written in Lua (more on this at https://youtu.be/qv6UVOQ0F44)

The AI runs successfully in the Lua (v.5.1) console of the BizHawk emulator (v.2.1.1), but I'm getting an error when trying to reload a previous state of the algorithm.

After opening the file, it seems like file:read("*number") will always return 0, whereas read("*all") and "*line" both read the content correctly. I've also tried "*n" with no luck.

Full script at: https://pastebin.com/ZZmSNaHX

```
function loadFile(filename)
  local file = io.open(filename, "r")
  pool = newPool()
  pool.generation = file:read("*number")
  pool.maxFitness = file:read("*number")
  ...

function writeFile(filename)
  local file = io.open(filename, "w")
  file:write(pool.generation .. "\n")
  file:write(pool.maxFitness .. "\n")
  ...
```

The file generated starts with:

```
18[LF]
1938[LF]
...
```

But still, I only see 0s in the console:

```
console.writeline("Gen " .. pool.generation) --> "Gen 0"
console.writeline("Max Fitness " .. pool.maxFitness) --> "Max Fitness 0"
```

What's also puzzling is that this script has been discussed in different forums and no one seems to report the same issue.

Comment: BTW, `file:write(pool.generation,"\n")` is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the BizHawk emulator is using a customized version of Lua.
This issue appeared in version 2.1.1 of the emulator. Previous releases are working fine.

Thanks for your help community

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the affected version? That way this can be useful for others.

Comment: done editing. As bizhawk is the culprit, I will also edit the title to include that

Answer (score 0):

The format to read a number is 'n', file:read('n').  See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read for details on read() format specifiers.

Comment: It looks like this has changed over time:
`"*all" reads the whole file
"*line" reads the next line
"*number" reads a number
num reads a string with up to num characters`
https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html
Nevertheless, why would *all and *line work and not *number

Comment: Yes that is old Lua 5.0 syntax.  Maybe re-try with a current Lua?  BTW, I don't understand why an obviously correct answer gets downvoted...

Comment: [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2) says, "Option names in io.read do not have a starting `*` anymore. For compatibility, Lua will continue to accept (and ignore) this character." Simply speaking, `"*number"` option is still working in Lua 5.3, and your answer does not provide a method to solve the problem described by OP.

Comment: Version is 5.1 so the suggested answer returns an error. I can't try with a more recent lua version as it is embedded in the console emulator. No luck either with tonumber(file:read())

Answer (score 0):

Around that time, BizHawk added an alternate c# lua implementation 'kopilua' in an effort to workaround deep crashy problems. One of kopilua's several shortcomings is noncompliant string parsing and file IO. You must use config > customize > advanced > Lua+LuaInterface in order to use normal lua; it won't have this problem.